# Is it possible to prevent length extension attacks

Tags: hash, sha-1, length-extension

Is it possible to prevent length extension attacks without using any other hash algorithm than SHA-1?

Comment: HMAC is the standard approach for turning a hash into a MAC/PRF.

Comment: First of all, you should not use SHA-1. For SHA-512 you could simply truncate to, for instance, 160 bits, the output size of SHA-1. However if you're stuck with SHA-1 then removing too many bits may leave you vulnerable to attacks that try and generate a collision - other than the ones that already exist, of course. Interesting question. HMAC is of course possible, but that requires a key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Without a key, length extension attacks don't make much sense.

Comment: Oh thank you, now I'll spend the rest of the evening thinking about situations where they do make sense without a key ;)

Comment: @CodesInChaos Can you describe how it is help to prevent in more details?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm pretty sure you can find tons of examples with web apps and other web related stuff. Like uploading files and renaming them using SHA-1, etc.

Comment: @Lery No, that would still change the hash value. Anybody can recalculate a hash value, so for that kind of situation length extension attacks are not applicable; the attacker either has the ability to change the hash value or not.